# How to perform full text search on elasticsearch using springboot 2.x?

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, nosql, full-text-search

I am trying to implement a full text search on nosql datatbase.I tried with elasticsearch which serves the purpose with springboot 1.5.x but isn't compatible with springboot 2.x and I need to use latest springboot.can any one suggest work around on using elastic search with springboot 2.x or any other method to implement full text search compatible with latest spring boot?

Comment: Are you sure you can't use compatible versions?
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/3.2.0.RC3/reference/html/#preface.versions

Comment: @DovVachman I am exploring elasticsearch and springboot for first time.I am sure I need springboot version to be latest i.e 2.2 but what this url points out is Spring Data Elasticsearch version.I am not sure how they relate.Can you please help?

Comment: @DovVachman Springboot 2.2.x doesn't support NodeBuilder required for elasticsearch, so yes their compatibility is required.

Comment: You need not rely on Spring Data Elasticsearch dependency, instead you can directly use client provided by elasticsearch i.e. Elasticsearch Java Highlevel REST client. You can add dependency as mentioned [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-getting-started-maven.html).

Comment: @NishantSaini Can you give a more elaborated answer please.DO you have link to any sample github repo where Java Highlevel REST client has been used for full text search.Or any other method to implement full text search using springboot 2.x